# Leaflet Draw how to trigger button events from outside the map

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I've got a leaflet draw instance where I need buttons outside the map to start / cancel draw actions. I have successfully triggered draw start with

`map.Draw.Polyline(map, myDrawControlInstance.options.polyline).enable();`

but the only action I could find anywhere in the API that is mentioned to cancel a draw action: `map.Draw.Polyline(map, myDrawControlInstance.options.polyline).disable();` does not trigger the cancel action.

How can I mimic all buttons that appear in the Leaflet Draw interface when drawing, editing, deleting, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the answer. You need to store the draw handler before doing enable.

```
new L.Draw.Polyline(map, drawControl.options.polyline).enable();
```

returns `undefined`

The correct implementation would be:

```
const drawHandler = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, drawControl.options.polyline);
drawHandler.enable();
//After drawing
drawHandler.disable();
```

Here is a github issue referencing a similar issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/370

Answer (score 0):

Found a post somewhere from almost 10 years ago with the answer.

You have to keep the drawHandler that's returned by the new `L.Draw.` method and call the `cancel()` on it.

start a draw from outside:

```
const drawHandler = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, drawControl.options.polyline).enable();
```

cancel the draw from outside the map:

```
drawHandler.disable();
```

Comment: "Found a post somewhere from almost 10 years ago with the answer."  A link would have been good.